# Apply kurtosis to a distribution in python

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, distribution

I have a dataset which is in the format of

frequency, direction, normalised power spectral density, spread, skewness, kurtosis

I am able to visualise the distribution of a specific record using the code from the top answer in [skew normal distribution in scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5885349/1135883) but I am not sure how to apply a kurtosis value to a distribution?

```
from scipy import linspace
from scipy import pi,sqrt,exp
from scipy.special import erf
from pylab import plot,show

def pdf(factor, x):
    return (100*factor)/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-x**2/2)

def cdf(x):
    return (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2))) / 2

def skew(x,e=0,w=1,a=0, norm_psd=1):
    t = (x-e) / w
    return 2 / w * pdf(norm_psd, t) * cdf(a*t)

n = 540
e = 341.9 # direction
w = 59.3 # spread
a = 3.3 # skew
k = 4.27 # kurtosis
n_psd = 0.5 # normalised power spectral density
x = linspace(-90, 450, n) 


p = skew(x, e, w, a, n_psd)
print max(p)
plot(x,p)
show()
```

**Edit:** I removed skew normal from my title as I don't think it is actually possible to apply a kurtosis value to the above distribution, I think a different distribution is necessary, as direction is involved a distribution from circular statistics may be more appropriate?

Thanks to the answer below I can apply kurtosis using the pdf_mvsk function demonstrated in the code below, unfortunately my skew values cause a negative y value, but the answer satisfies my question.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.extras as extras

pdffunc = extras.pdf_mvsk([341.9, 59.3, 3.3, 4.27])
range = np.arange(0, 360, 0.1)
plt.plot(range, pdffunc(range))
plt.show()
```

Comment: your question seems confused.  you removed skew from the title because you "don't think it is actually possible to apply a *kurtosis* value".  why is "kurtosis" in that quoted text?  what is the logic?  and why do you think circular stats is relevant?  surely one way to add kurtosis is to simply raise the pdf to some power (greater than one for more peak, less than one for less) and then renormalise.  of course, there's no guarantee this will leave the other params unchanged, which is what you want, ideally.

Comment: The results you are getting contain *negative* values, because "*In the Gram-Charlier distribution it is possible that the density becomes negative. This is when the deviation from the normal distribution is too large.*"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have mean, standard deviation, skew and kurtosis, then you can build an approximately normal distribution with those moments using Gram-Charlier expansion.

I looked into this some time ago, scipy.stats had a function that was wrong and was removed.

I don't remember what the status of this is, since it was a long time ago that I put this in the statsmodels sandbox
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.extras.pdf_mvsk.html#statsmodels.sandbox.distributions.extras.pdf_mvsk