# Random numbers based on Skewness

Tags: python, random

I posted a similar question and for some reason, I am not able to access that.

I am trying to generate random numbers (say 50 numbers) between 1 and 100,000 for a given Kurtosis. In other words, when I input the kurtosis to the script, it should generate 50 random numbers between 1 and 100,000 and print them on the console. I am trying to do this in Python.

I am new to Python and I did something like below, which does generate numbers, but based on the mean. How do I do this with Kurtosis as the input?

```
import scipy.stats as stats
a, b = 500, 600
mu, sigma = 550, 30
dist = stats.truncnorm((a - mu) / sigma, (b - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)

print(dist.rvs(10))
```

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on skewness or kurtosis? They are not the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating numbers (distribution) for a given Kurtosis or skewness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898729/generating-numbers-distribution-for-a-given-kurtosis-or-skewness)