# How do I generate data with specified mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis in Python?

Tags: python, statistics, simulation

I want to generate data in Python that behaves like real stock market data, which means I need to be able to specify and play around with all of the first four moments. Only being able to control skewness or only kurtosis is unfortunately not enough.

I found some answers here: [How to generate a distribution with a given mean, variance, skew and kurtosis in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604389/how-to-generate-a-distribution-with-a-given-mean-variance-skew-and-kurtosis-in), however I seem unable to gain control of the properties with the gengamma distribution.

I know there are tons of distributions here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions, maybe I can use one of them in some clever way? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better using the gengamma function in scipy since you have all the parameters to control the shape of the distribution.

```
from scipy.stats import gengamma
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gengamma.html

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of potential choices of distribution family.

The classic example would be the Pearson family of distributions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution

These encompass scaled (including multiplication by negative values to get left-skewed distributions) and shifted versions of the beta, gamma, inverse gamma, t and F distributions, among others.