# Plotting resulting fitted curve with scipy

Tags: python, scipy

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884768/skew-normal-distribution-in-scipy), what about if I want to overplot the fitted curve over the data points? Should I define the fitting function again?

Leastsq method has lacking documentation and examples, and I have some troubles in understanding the arguments it needs.

According to that, if I define:

```
def optm(l, x, y):
    return skew(x, l[0], l[1], l[2]) - y
```

Then, is it correct to fit in the following way:

```
out_param = leastsq(optm, v1[:], args = (x_values, y_values), maxfev = 100000, full_output = 1)
```

(where `v1[:]` is the vector with the initial guess parameters)?
And then, again, how can I plot the resulting curve?

I am still trying to understand so any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved in the following way:
The string code reported in the question was correct.
Then I saved the best-fit parameters in another vector:

```
p = out_param[0]
```

Then, I used the skew function to obtain the new (fitted) y_values:

```
new_y_val = skew(x_values, p[0], p[1], p[2])
```

And finally I can make a plot with these new vectors:

```
plot(time1, pl)
```