# Finding a probability density function that reproduces a histogram in Python

Tags: python, scipy, histogram, curve-fitting, probability-density

So all the data that I actually have is a picture of a histogram from which I can get heights and bin width, the median and one sigma errors.

The histogram is skewed, so the 16th and 84th quantile are not symmetric. I found that the median and the errors can be replicated with a skewed gaussian function, however the resulting histogram, from my found pdf, is difficult to match no mater how much I play with bin numbers and bin widths.

I understand that I can't possibly recreate the histogram exactly, but I will be very happy with something that is close enough.

My best idea is to loop through possible parameters of the skewed gaussian, make a histogram, somehow quantify the difference (like difference in heights at all points) and find best one. I think that might be a very long process though and I'm very sure there is something in scipy that does this quicker. Please refer me to anything useful if possible.

Comment: If you have spotted a distribution that might fit, you could normalize the histogram to a density and then do a least square fit of the parameters onto this histogram. However this is far from optimal - by using only the histogram you already lost a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your best shot is to treat the data as points and fit a function with [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884768/skew-normal-distribution-in-scipy) might also help: