# How to draw samples from lmfit model?

Tags: lmfit

I have a skewed Gaussian model in lmfit that fits my data. Now I would like to draw a sample from it, but I could nowhere in the documentation find how? Is the correct approach to simply implement the model function yourself in my case [the skewed normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) or is there a function in lmfit for this?

My code:

```
model = SkewedGaussianModel()

params = model.make_params(amplitude=60, center=30, sigma=10, gamma=0)

result = model.fit(y, params, x=x)
print(result.fit_report())
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit)
plt.show()
# something like this
print(result.model.eval(random.random())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition for skewed Gaussian used in lmfit is given at
http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/builtin_models.html#skewedgaussianmodel
with code at
https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/master/lmfit/lineshapes.py#L213.

I believe that what you are looking for is the "inverse transform sampling". See http://www.nehalemlabs.net/prototype/blog/2013/12/16/how-to-do-inverse-transformation-sampling-in-scipy-and-numpy/ for hints on how to do that. There is not a built-in method for this in lmfit, as lmfit does not necessarily assert that the model being fitted is a probability distribution function.  It might be worth considering adding such a capability.

Comment: Thank you for these resources. This is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Until somebody can find the function, or confirm the nonexistence of it here is how I did it:

```
def pdf(x):
    return 1/sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-x**2/2)

def cdf(x):
    return (1 + erf(x/sqrt(2))) / 2

def skew(x,e=0,w=1,a=0):
    t = (x-e) / w
    return 2 / w * pdf(t) * cdf(a*t)
    # You can of course use the scipy.stats.norm versions
    # return 2 * norm.pdf(t) * norm.cdf(a*t)
```

copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884768/skew-normal-distribution-in-scipy)